# Google maps shortcode

Tags: wordpress, custom-post-type

Why this code don't work?

```
<?php
echo do_shortcode('[pw_map address="global $wp_query; $postid = $wp_query->post->ID; echo get_post_meta($postid, 'codigo_postal', true);" height="120px"]');
?>
```

value of codigo_postal is 28004. if i put this, works!

```
<?php
echo do_shortcode('[pw_map address="28004" height="120px"]');
?>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

this is the final code, if you change yours, vote you! and delete this of course

```
<?php
global $wp_query;
$postid = $wp_query->post->ID;
echo do_shortcode("[pw_map address='".get_post_meta($postid, 'codigo_postal', true)."' height='120px']");
?>
```

Answer (score 1):

This is a best guess as I don't know the plugin personally, seeing as this is php, the way you're writing variables appears to be incorrect. You're trying to define variables within a string, as well as trying to echo them out.

Try this;

```
<?php
global $wp_query;
$postid = $wp_query->post->ID;
echo do_shortcode('[pw_map address="'.get_post_meta($postid, 'codigo_postal', true).'" height="120px"]');
```

Comment: Yes, sorry I've updated the code. I missed a couple of single quotes. It should be ok now.

Comment: the final code is after this comment. Vote for you, really thanks!